# Is is possible to train Azure OCR

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying out Azure Cognitive Services OCR to scan in an identity document. It works fairly well but I was wondering if it is possible to train the OCR engine or somehow link it to a learning service to improve character recognition ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can train Azure OCR, but there is one new Azure service called Form Recognizer which gives better results than the previous OCR service and also you can train it on custom data.